# Convert a node.js class to a worker automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, worker

I have an time consuming task to execute on a node.js server. I want to test how it would perform when run inside a separete thread. I want to expose the class from a worker withoth having to code manually every part. Is there a node internal function or module that can do that? Thanks

```
class RunInWorker {

  constructor (starta, startb) {
    this.sum = starta + startb;
  }

  addSync(a, b) {
    return a + b + this.sum;
  }

  async addAsync(a, b) {
    await (new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, 3000); }));
    return a + b + this.sum;
  }

}

/** @type {\RunInWorker} */
let worker = new require('./wrap-worker.js')(RunInWorker, [5, 5]);

(async () => {
  console.log(worker);
  console.log(await worker.addSync(3, 4), 'should be', 17);
  console.log(await worker.addAsync(3, 8), 'should be', 21);
})();
```

Im currently converting the class toString and than create a worker on the fly but I dont think this is the best way to go...

```
// wrap-worker.js
const { Worker, isMainThread } = require('worker_threads');

function WrapWorker(OBJECT, OBJECT_ARGS) {

  if (isMainThread) {

    let workerCode = `
const { parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');

let OBJECT = ` + OBJECT.toString() + `

let INSTANCE = new OBJECT(...workerData);

parentPort.on('message', async function (data) {
  if (data.method) {
    let method = INSTANCE[data.method];
    if (typeof method === 'function') {
      let response;
      if (method.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction') response = await method.apply(INSTANCE, data.arguments);
      else response = method.apply(INSTANCE, data.arguments);
      parentPort.postMessage({ rid: data.rid, valid: 1, response: response });
    } else {
      parentPort.postMessage({ rid: data.rid, valid: 0 });
    }
  }
});`;

    let instance = new Worker(workerCode, { eval: true, workerData: OBJECT_ARGS });

    let methodsProxy = {};
    let methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(OBJECT.prototype);

    let rid = 0;
    let requests = [];
    for (let mid in methods) {
      let methodId = methods[mid];
      methodsProxy[methodId] = function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          rid++;
          requests[rid] = { resolve: resolve, reject: reject };
          instance.postMessage({ method: methodId, arguments: Array.from(arguments), rid: rid });
        });
      };
    }

    instance.on('message', function (data) {
      if (data.rid) {
        if (data.valid) requests[data.rid].resolve(data.response);
        else requests[data.rid].reject();
        delete requests[data.rid];
      }
    });

    return methodsProxy;

  }

}

module.exports = WrapWorker;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// wrap-worker.js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');

function WrapWorker(OBJECT, OBJECT_ARGS) {
  if (require('worker_threads').isMainThread) {
    const workerCode = `
      const { parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');
      const OBJECT = ${OBJECT.toString()};

      const instance = new OBJECT(...workerData);

      parentPort.on('message', async (data) => {
        try {
          const method = instance[data.method];
          if (typeof method === 'function') {
            const response = await method.apply(instance, data.arguments);
            parentPort.postMessage({ rid: data.rid, valid: true, response });
          } else {
            parentPort.postMessage({ rid: data.rid, valid: false });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          parentPort.postMessage({ rid: data.rid, valid: false });
        }
      });
    `;

    const instance = new Worker(workerCode, { eval: true, workerData: OBJECT_ARGS });

    const methodsProxy = {};
    const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(OBJECT.prototype);

    let rid = 0;
    const requests = {};
    for (const methodId of methods) {
      methodsProxy[methodId] = (...args) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          rid++;
          requests[rid] = { resolve, reject };
          instance.postMessage({ method: methodId, arguments: args, rid });
        });
    }

    instance.on('message', (data) => {
      const request = requests[data.rid];
      if (request) {
        if (data.valid) {
          request.resolve(data.response);
        } else {
          request.reject();
        }
        delete requests[data.rid];
      }
    });

    return methodsProxy;
  }
}

module.exports = WrapWorker;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on what you changed and why.

Comment: I diff compared it, it seems like some type optimization and a try catch when calling methods. Indeed its a better way that my prototype but still not revolutionary. Thanks for tip bro

Comment: I apologize for not providing an explanation regarding this, I thought I pointed out everything but I see there is no explanation.

Regarding the question you mentioned, if you have a time-consuming task to execute on a Node.js server and want to test its performance when run in a separate thread, Node.js provides the worker_threads module for creating and managing worker threads. You can use this module to run JavaScript code in parallel threads, offloading the processing to separate worker threads and improving overall performance.

Comment: In the code I provided, the wrap-worker.js module facilitates creating a worker thread and exposing the class methods through a proxy interface. It abstracts away the manual handling of communication between the main thread and the worker thread.

By utilizing the worker_threads module and the WrapWorker function in my code, you can easily create a worker thread and interact with the class methods without the need for manual code implementation. This will allow you to test the performance of your time-consuming task within a separate thread efficiently.